# How to convert decimal back BCD?

Tags: c, bcd

I am able to convert BCD to decimal, for example I can convert 0x11 to 11 instead of 17 in decimal. This is the code I used.

```
unsigned char hex = 0x11;
unsigned char backtohex ;

int dec = ((hex & 0xF0) >> 4) * 10 + (hex & 0x0F);
```

Now I want to convert `dec` back to BCD representation. I want 11 to be converted back to 0x11 not 0x0B. I am kind of confused as how to go back.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use bit manipulation, but division and modulo operators in a loop.

Comment: Your hex to dec function is flawed; e.g., 0x0A and 0x10 both convert to 10. So there is no way to "go back." Maybe you don't mean hexadecimal at all, just BCD.

Comment: I mean just BCD, updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input is always between 0 and 99, inclusive:

```
unsigned char hex = ((dec / 10) << 4) | (dec % 10);
```

Simply take the upper digit and shift it left by one nibble, and *or* the lower digit in place.

Comment: Yes they are between 0 and 99