# Convert 1-byte number to decimal

Tags: c, flash

First of all I'm sorry for the confusing title.
I'm reading [Adobe's specs of SWF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) and I saw a statement I'm not really sure how to code.

> A one-byte version number follows the signature. The version number is not an ASCII character, but an 8-bit
>   number. For example, for SWF 4, the version byte is 0x04, not the ASCII character “4” (0x34).

This effectively means that `0x20` is not a space, but actually the number `20`.

Now, let's say I have this:

```
unsigned char c[1] = { 0x20 };
```

How would I get an integer with the value `20` out of `c`?

EDIT:

It turns out that not what I'm looking for. The byte with the version actually follows this scheme: [Chart of SWF versions to Flash versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537076/chart-of-swf-versions-to-flash-versions)

Comment: I read that as saying it would be the number `0x20`, not `20`...

Comment: Why would you want to get the number from the integer?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, read again. `0x04` is not `EOT`, but actually the number `4` (which's HEX representation is `0x34`).

Comment: Sure, but 0x4 and 4 are the same thing. 0x20 and 20 are not.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm not really sure about that. Mind to make a simple printf with it?

Comment: 0x20 and 20 are not the same thing. 0x04 IS 4. 0x20 (which is hex) is actually the number 32 (if you use %d - it IS 20 with %x)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth just what Toam said.

Comment: @alexandernst: yes, Toam is saying the same thing as me. You are misinterpreting the spec.

Comment: Also note that since the question wants an integer output, %d is the correct format to use. 0x20 should return 32, not 20. with %x, FF would return "FF" which is not an integer.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Again, as what Toam said. Version 11 of SWF is `0x11`, and not `0x0b`. i need to get an integeer out of that (weird imho) representation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139264/how-to-convert-decimal-back-bcd/

Comment: I think SWF 11 IS 0x0b: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351370/how-can-i-determine-what-flash-player-version-a-swf-was-published-for

Comment: @Toam No, it's not. I have a valid SWF v11 file and it's 0x11.

Comment: Nowhere does the spec say "convert the byte value to a hex string representation, then interpret the digits as decimal, and then convert back".  If that's *genuinely* what one needs to do, then that's a terrible spec.

Comment: You are sure it is not SWF 17 and Flash 11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537076/chart-of-swf-versions-to-flash-versions

Comment: Let me re-check, but I'm almost sure it's v11.

Comment: @alexandernst: "If you need to knows the mapping between Flash Player / AIR names to SWF version (for example, 11.4 is SWF 17)," (page 13)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are right, indeed. I should actually use the table you linked to convert to the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
char string[16];
int  value;
unsigned char c[1] = { 0x20 };

snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%x", c[0]);
value = strtol(string, NULL, 10);
```

this will work as long as the hex representation of the number has a textual decimal equivalent, i.e. it wont work for `0xA0` for example.

Comment: That will reinterpret a byte of what we used to call BCD as a decimal number (although it's clunky: you could just do `c[0] - 6*(c[0]>>4)`), but it seems highly unlikely that it what is really required here.